# How can I make a c# console appear on second plane

Tags: c#, console

Well I´ve created a basic program that is executed from a macro program that allows me to have multiple keyboards blah blah blah.
The matter is that my app opens correctly and reproduces its sound correcly, but if I am in a full screen app it minimizes. I,ve tried this but it also appears for some milliseconds.

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

   namespace Sound001
   {
   class Program
   {
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IntPtr hwnd;
        hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
        ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);

        switch (int.Parse(args[0])) {
            case 0:
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\soundmacros\0.wav");
                player.PlaySync();
                break;
        }
        switch (int.Parse(args[0]))
        {
            case 1:
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\soundmacros\1.wav");
                player.PlaySync();
                break;
        }
        switch (int.Parse(args[0]))
        {
            case 2:
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\soundmacros\2.wav");
                player.PlaySync();
                break;
        }
        switch (int.Parse(args[0]))
        {
            case 3:
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\soundmacros\3.wav");
                player.PlaySync();
                break;
        }
        switch (int.Parse(args[0]))
        {
            case 4:
                System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\soundmacros\4.wav");
                player.PlaySync();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You are using "switch" with wrong syntax. Look here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/switch/

Comment: Well the app works except for the seconplane part, it reproduces the sound but i don´t want it to appear on screen, I´ll repair that but please try help me whith that

Comment: If you don't want UI, you can create Windows Service to play sound.

Comment: Does that allow to play Sync?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer researching, is so simple. Just go to Project -> SomeApp Properties... -> Application -> Output Type And change it to Windows Application instead of console app and it works.